# Run a Python script on a host without Internet connection

Tags: python, pip

I read all the proposed related questions but didn't find an answer to my case.

As for the title, I need to run a Python script (e.i. not an executable created with pyInstall) on a Windows VM that is not connected to the Internet. I can only download packages via browser.

Install Python is not a problem, but pip doesn't work, so I have the libraries issue.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How do you reconcile "a Windows VM that is not connected to the Internet. I can only download packages via browser"

Comment: Pip works just fine if you give it local wheel or tar files of packages

Comment: This isn't about *running* a script, but in installing the packages it needs. If you don't have a network connection, you are going to have to download them on the host machine and install them via a shared disk (or whatever mechanism your virtualization software supports for transferring from host to guest.

Comment: You can also establish a network connection for installation, then turn it off before running the script.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263696/how-do-i-include-3rd-party-modules-with-my-python-scripts

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry for the sentence that was not very clear. I try to be more detailed: I am on a Windows VM where the proxy configurations only allow me to browse or download packages via browser.

Comment: In that case, my answer should work for you just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [PyPi](https://%20https://pypi.org), where pip searches for packages, and find a package you are interested in, you can click on "Download Files" on the left panel. Using numpy as an example: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files

[image]

You can manually download the files that you want for each package and install them directly with pip. Keep in mind that the first couple of rounds will likely involve error messages telling you that there are missing dependencies. You will have to go back to PyPi and get those dependencies as well, until everything installs correctly.

You may want to check the following question for information regarding manual dependency management: [How to extract dependencies from a PyPi package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14154756/2988730).